# Help with wording proof (prime factorisation)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am required to prove: If $a \mid m$ and $b \mid m$ for $a,b,m \in \mathbb{N}$, then lcm($a,b)\mid m$.

I have come up with a proof using unique prime factorisation but am having a lot of difficulty trying to word it in the simplest form.

So basically I start with
$m = p_1^{e_1}*p_2^{e_2}*...*p_k^{e_k} $

Then I want to say $a = p_{a_1}^{f_1}*...*p_{a_s}^{f_s}$ where $ p_{a_1}^{f_1}*...*p_{a_s}^{f_s}\in p_1^{e_1}*p_2^{e_2}*...*p_k^{e_k} $

i.e. $a$ is made up of prime factors that must be in $m$'s prime factors.
And the same for b.

And then we take the lcm(a,b) by taking the minimum of the prime factors of a and b. And since these prime factors are in $m$, the proof is complete.

Is there a way to write this without using a lot of subscripts?

Comment: Couple of typos: I think you mean $\mid$ rather than $\in$. Also the lcm should be the maximum of the prime factors of $a$ and $b$ rather than the minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a cleaner way to present your argument.

Since we have unique factorisation, it suffices to check separately that each prime power dividing $lcm(a,b)$ also divides $m$. So let $p^e \mid lcm(a,b)$, where $e$ is the maximum power of $p$ dividing $lcm(a,b)$. Due to the construction of the lcm, $e$ is the maximum power of $p$ dividing both $a$ and $b$, so we have $p^e \mid a$ or $p^e \mid b$. But since both $a$ and $b$ divide $m$, so does $p^e$, and we are therefore done.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much simpler proof if you observe $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$ is a generator of the ideal $(a)\cap(b)$. Now $m\mid a$ means $m\in (a)$. Similarly $m\in(b)$, hence $m\in (a)\cap(b)=(\operatorname{lcm}(a,b))$. In other words, $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)\mid m$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $l.c.m(a,b)=l$. Let $l\nmid m$ .Then, $m=lq+r$ for some integer $q$ and $r$ such that $0<r<l$. So, $m-lq=r$.

As $a|m$ and $b|m$, also $a|l$ and $b|l$ $=>$ $a|r$ and $b|r.$ So, $r$ is a common multiple of $a$ and $b$. But, $l$ is the least common multiple and $r<l$. Therefore, it is a contradiction and hence $l|m.$